# problem running utorrent server on cent os 5.5

Tags: centos, openssl, bittorrent

i am trying to run utorrent server on remote machine via ssh

µTorrent server version :[alpha (3.0 build 25053)](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux)

it throws error at startup

```
./utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

dependency check shows

```
    ldd ./utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00bfa000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00694000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0059f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x0041e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0090c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00c05000)
```

but openssl 1.x is already installed

so whats going on here ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
ln -s /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8e /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

next error:

```
utserver: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./utserver)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your openssl rpm for what files it installed, does that list of files include `libssl.so.0.9.8.*`? If so, what folder did that file get installed to?